# Is mx having any expansion in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I am a beginner for flex. I know about the mx package. In this package, the mx having any expansion?

And anyone can tell me the correct expansion for MXML?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially there is no full form for mx but have a look at the entry from wikipedia.

> Adobe Systems, which acquired Macromedia in December 2005, gives no
>   official meaning for the acronym MXML. Some developers suggest it
>   should stand for "Magic eXtensible Markup Language" (which is a
>   backronym). It is likely that the name comes from the MX suffix given
>   to Macromedia Studio products released in 2002 and 2004, or simply
>   "Macromedia eXtensible Markup Language".

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML)

Also if you are starting new, go through these videos and they will give you a lot of good information about Flex - [Flex in a Week video training](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the namespace to use for the MX components?

If so then the following is what you are after.

```
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Comment: In flex, s means spark component. Then mx means what? If it's denoting MXML, Than what is meant by MXML?